# Next.js - 'yarn build' failed

Tags: next.js

When I'm trying to build my Next.js app for production I got the following error:

[image]

Seems 'API_KEY' is undefined. Can't destructure this property from publicRuntimeConfig. This error happens on pages where I use `getStaticProps` or `getStaticPaths` built in functions.

Here is my next.config.js:

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer");
const nextRuntimeDotenv = require("next-runtime-dotenv");

const withConfig = nextRuntimeDotenv({ public: ["API_URL", "API_KEY"] });

const nextConfig = {
    analyzeServer: ["server", "both"].includes(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE),
    analyzeBrowser: ["browser", "both"].includes(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE),
    bundleAnalyzerConfig: {
        server: {
            analyzerMode: "static",
            reportFilename: "../bundles/server.html",
        },
        browser: {
            analyzerMode: "static",
            reportFilename: "../bundles/client.html",
        },
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        PROXY_MODE: process.env.PROXY_MODE,
        API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
        STATIC_PATH: process.env.STATIC_PATH,
    },
};

module.exports = withConfig(
    withPlugins([[withCSS], [withSass], [withBundleAnalyzer]], nextConfig)
);
```

I have researched official docs and google similar problem but seems with no result. Any ideas why Next.js yarn build failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you can find this. `A page that relies on publicRuntimeConfig must use getInitialProps`   ( https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration ) I think you should put it somewhere else. Check the environment variables section https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables